# What is the probability to be after $n$ random jumps of unit length in space within a distance of radius $r$ from the start?

Tags: probability-distributions

Assume a particle, at instant 0 at the origin of three dimensional euclidean space  jumps at each tick of the clock exactly one unit 
  from its  current position into a random direction. By this we mean: any two patches of the same area of the unit sphere centered 
  at the current position have equal probability to receive the particle after its next jump; i.o.w. we assume uniform distribution
  for the directions selected from the unit sphere.

Question: What is - as a function of $r$ - the probability to encounter the particle after exactly $n$ random jumps within 
   the 0-centered ball $B=B(0,r)$ of radius $r.$

Together with my student I have on this problem exact results up to $n=4$: the probability distributions are in each of the
   cases $n=1,2,3,4$  piecewise polynomial  functions of $r$ and from this we have even a precise (but slightly complicated)
   conjecture for general $n.$   The proof up to 4 needs 
  laborious computations of volumes and before proceeding with more research, we would like to know whether this  so 
  natural problem  is already treated in the literature (or perhaps buried in more general results).  We have searched  a lot in Zentralblatt and on the Internet and looked in books on random walks, but not found anything that seems decisevely of  help.

( I found questions (and answers) somewhat related to this on this site but not 
exactly this. See the information given in the `essay'
"Proof: Mean and Variance of the squared distance of a random walk in n-dimensional space")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has traditionally been called the "problem of flights", or of "random flights", and is connected with "radial functions" and "Hankel transforms".  (But if you google "problem of flights" you will be swamped by articles about aviation.)

For $u\in\mathbb R^3$ the expectation $\phi(u)=E\exp(i\langle u,X\rangle)$ for $X$ uniformly distributed on the unit sphere is given by $\phi(u)=\sin(|u|)/|u|$ (this follows from the fact that each coordinate of $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$); "all" you need to do  is find the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi^n$.

A 1947 [paper of Quenouille](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-the-problem-of-random-flights/49196A1524F06021380ABB6E2AEFE373) is one classical reference; it cites a 1943 paper of [Chandrasekhar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=(1)+Chandrasekhar+S.+Rev.+Mod.+Phys.+15+(1943)+1.).  Some [recent course notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~faris/methodsweb/hankel.pdf) are relevant: see equation (22) and what leads up to it.  This 1985 [survey paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00348451?LI=true) gives a wealth of historical info, including many other references.  (Since this work mostly dates from the first half of the last century, before the modern notation and terminology of probability theory stabilized, these references have a somewhat quaint or antique feel to them.)

Comment: Thank you, i will have to study your hint. (I am not expert in probability theory.)

Comment: I have added references to my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Incredible, i will have to have a closer look yet, but the papers by Chandrasekhar and Quenouille seem to solve in fact the problem... they have formulas which are of exactly of the type we got till n=4...  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks you, glad to help.  I have added another  reference at the end of my post.

Comment: All your references, are very useful, in particular also your last Dutka. I'm studying them intensely and hope to be back in a month.

Comment: Dear Kimchi lover: my student and i are finishing a preprint on the special random flight problem i asked. Our solution seems more elementary (although it is not simple) than what we read in the literature we owe to you. We would like to thank your real identity in our preprint.  In case you agree please send me an e-mail. We will continue to study the papers you indicated in the next months.

Comment: This is very flattering, but I would prefer to be "an anonymous poster on math.stackexchange", analogous somehow to being an anonymous reviewer.